# Set one homepage for all browsers simultaneously

Tags: windows, browser, script

For testing purposes, I would like to set the homepage of all browsers installed on my computer — Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Safari — to the same page. I'd like to do this all at the same time. I imagine that there's an application that has an input box for the URL I want to use as homepage and an OK button to set it in all browsers.

Where can I get a utility or script that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an HTML document anywhere on your system that includes a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to your desired actual home page. Point all browsers' home page to that html document using the `file://` URL scheme (or, if you always have a local web server running, place it there), and edit it as needed. If required, see [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) on how to disable caching that document.

Comment: Or do you seriously want to spend your time writing software for this, unless it's about the learning experience?

Comment: That's a pretty nifty solution. Like creating a link that you can point where you will, and then point the browsers to that link.

Comment: If you're running a local web server, or have a webspace with some scripting support, you can even send the appropriate HTML headers instead, to speed this process up a bit.

Comment: ooh great idea! I will do that. Very simple. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up making my own static home page with a collection of work-related links. For the original purpose I just update some querystring values in the links and it gives me what I want. But I also have links to different servers, the intranet and other web apps within the company :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that there is an application that will do this for you.

IE will saves it's homepage in the registry, probably in the HK Current User hive, Firefox, probably in a database in the user profile folder, Chrome is probably similar to Firefox.

This means that any automated multi-browser update system will necessarily be relatively complex, as the various homepages cannot be modified using the same method.

Comment: interesting. I suppose I could write an app myself. Just have to research how each does it. Maybe it's not even possible to set from outside the browsers. I am now thinking of just having some batch files to do it. Create an environment var with one and just have a .cmd for each browser to open that variable via command line

Comment: Firefox, as an open source browser, has pretty good development documentation that should be quite helpful for this. Chrome may as well, though it's probably a little more closed than Firefox. IE will probably be the easiest as it is simply a reg edit. Safari: I have no clue.